# Joining datasets with greater than less than conditions

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

We’ve two datasets that look like this:

```
Dataset A: App specific data that contains (among other fields): ip_address

Dataset B: Location data that contains start_ip_address_int, end_ip_address_int, latitude, longitude
```

We’re (left) joining these two datasets as:

```
A.ip_address >= B.start_ip_address_int AND A.ip_address <= B.end_ip_address_int
```

When there's a match, we pick latitude & longitude from Dataset B.

This works fine but it takes a LONG time (over 20 minutes) to complete for SMALL datasets.

```
Dataset A => Usually contains 110,000
Dataset B => Contains 12.5 Million rows. This is “static” data. Hasn’t changed since August 2020.
```

When we looked at the **DAG**, it seems a **BroadcastNestedLoopJoin** is getting used which supposedly is very slow. It seems Spark selects it by default when we have “in equal” conditions such as “greater than”, “less than”.

What’s the best way to speed up this process?